# Add style when hover animation is finished

Tags: css

Is it possible to add another style when the hover animation is completely finished?

With the default hover all styles get applied at the same time.
So changing from `display: none` to `display: block` will override any transformation because the element will just appear out of nowhere.

In the following example something like this would be helpful, because right now you can trigger the hover effect from outside of the actual "hover area".

```css
.grid_content {
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: salmon;
}

.grid_hover {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.09, 0.37, 0.93);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bottom_left {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.text_overlay {
  top: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin: 0 15%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}

.background_overlay {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.box_overlay {
  border: 1.5px solid #000000;
  width: calc(100% - 2vw);
  height: calc(100% - 2vw);
  margin: 1vw;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid_content:hover > .grid_hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(0);
}


.hover_here {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_content">
  <div class="grid_hover bottom_left">
    <div class="text_overlay"> <p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="background_overlay"></div>

  </div>
</div>

<p class="hover_here">
Hover somewhere around here to see the "bug"
</p>
```

I also tried to just set `grid_hover` to `pointer-events: none;` that worked, but I can't use it because inside that div will be a button that has to be clickable.

My idea or what I want to achieve is something like this:

- `.grid_hover` is set to `display: none` at the beginning
- hovering on `.grid_content` will set it to `display: block` and after that happened the animation should run

Is there a way to make this work in just css without javascript?

Comment: Have you tried using overflow : hidden on your container ?

Comment: You would need to separate the transitions and allow for separate animation delays to stagger the transitions. Frankly, javascript might be simpler to just add another class after a delay.

Comment: @Xanthous Well, `overflow: hidden` did the trick here. Thanks!